# Sinatra - URL params in before block?

Tags: sinatra, block, parameters

I have something like this

```
get '/news/:news_slug/' do
  ...
end
```

What I've trying to do is access the `news_slug` in a `before` block, is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to do something like this myself, what I had to do was use the `before` block like so:

```
before '/news/:news_slug' do
  # Before news code
end
```

However, if you want to use the before block for *other* stuff also, you'll have to do what I did which is something like:

```
def news_before
  # Before news code
end

["/url_one", "/url_two", "/news/:news_slug"].each do |path|
  before path do
    if params[:news_slug]
      news_before
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh I see, let me try this and get back to you.